# On simpler ways of identifying whether linear momentum is conserved

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Is there a way / faster method to know if any system's linear momentum is conserved without building its Lagrangian and then applying Noether's procedure? For example, the system below. [image]

Comment: The conservation of linear momentum holds as long as you are following an inertial frame of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the Noether procedure shows that conservation of momentum is a consequence of a system being invariant under translation. So if you pick up your entire system and translate it all by a  certain distance and your system still looks the same then you will have conservation of **total** momentum. I.e the sum of momenta of all constituent parts of the system will remain constant in time, although individual momenta may change.

Otherwise you could just write down the expression for total momentum, differentiate with respect to time and apply the equations of motion to check explicitly whether its derivative is zero.